# ¿Cómo agregar a una lista de palabras la lista de sinónimos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, nlp, spacy

Tengo un conjunto de palabras `question_roots` y me gustaría agregarle todos los sinónimos de las palabras de este conjunto.

Por ejemplo con `question` : `When did Beyonce start becoming popular?` obtengo `question_roots` con tamizando

```
question_roots = [st.stem(chunk.root.head.text.lower()) for chunk in en_nlp(question).noun_chunks]
```

Y obtengo : `[start]`.

Por lo momento intenté :

```
from itertools import chain
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

print(question)
question_roots = [st.stem(chunk.root.head.text.lower()) for chunk in en_nlp(question).noun_chunks]

synonyms = []
synonyms += wordnet.synsets(word for word in question_roots)
print(synonyms)
```

Pero obtengo :

```
When did Beyonce start becoming popular?
['start']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-e9c1e94c1799> in <module>()
     10 synonyms = []
     11 print(type(word) for word in question_roots)
---> 12 synonyms += wordnet.synsets(word for words in question_roots)
     13 print(synonyms)

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py in synsets(self, lemma, pos, lang, check_exceptions)
   1531         of that language will be returned.
   1532         """
-> 1533         lemma = lemma.lower()
   1534 
   1535         if lang == 'eng':

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

En efecto parece que `word` en `question_roots` son `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb2a9406780>`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a este tutorial para obtener sinónimos / antónimos de NLTK WordNet en Python me las arreglé para hacer :

```
question = "When did Beyonce start becoming popular?"
synonyms = []
print(question_roots)
for word in question_roots:
    wordnet = wordnet.synsets(word)
    for synset in wordnet:
        name = synset.lemmas()[0].name()
        synonyms.append(name)
print(set(synonyms))
```

Y esto me da :

```
['start']
{'startle', 'start', 'beginning', 'depart', 'starting_signal', 'begin', 'get_down', 'originate'}
```

Pero no sabé si es efectivo.